# How do I remove a "null" column or legend in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, google-data-studio, google-data-studio-charts

I have a simple Google Sheet for my source for Google Data Studio charts. Legends in pie charts and columns in bar charts show a "null" that I can't explain. My columns display correctly but there's always an empty column or "null" in the pie chart legend. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Maybe a dumb suggestion but did you tried croping the the cells to keep only data ? (no blank cells) I personnly like to use the *Crop Sheet* add-on and I have never encounter this problem using Data studio.

Comment: Good thought but there are a LOT of columns in this project and the lengths vary. I'm not familiar with Crop Sheet but I'll look into it! Thanks!

Comment: Did you check every field from the data source ? Sometimes it's because Data-studio use by default the wrong type of format. (Try to add some relevant screenshot in your question and blur or hide sensitive data)

Comment: Yes, I've worked with that possibility. Sadly, I don't have permission in this forum, as a new member, to add a screenshot.

Comment: @BigAlMonroe you can upload to imgur and [edit] the post and add the link

Comment: Thank you Sathyajith. Last time I tried, I got a message telling me I couldn't. I hope this helps!

Comment: @BigAlMonroe I just got the same type of problem today and i fixed it by adding a calculation on the metric (i choosed min because it displayed the minimal value in my column which is 0) Hope it can help .

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Chart Filter" in the "Data" panel.
Click "+ Add a Filter"
At the bottom, click "Create a Filter"
First field, "Exclude"
Second field, select your field. In this case I'm assuming "Month"
Third field, "Is Null"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see that null one(s) is because you select the whole column(s) as data source (ex. A:C) instead of only selecting the range with data (ex. A1: C20).
You have 2 options:

1. by selecting A:C, you have to add a filter in chart setup section to exclude those rows without data
2. change the data source range to A1:C20
   The 1st is better as it'll be able to handle the potential change of the data.